# Can not get tweets about subject

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am trying to get tweets about 'GHAZA' , I try to get public discussion of "GHAZA" on twitter , how much people tweets about it and what they said. My code run but It return strange result.

```
>>> tweets=api.GetSearch("Ghaza",per_page=100,page=1)
>>> print tweets
[<twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4D70>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4DB0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4DF0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4E30>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4E70>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4EB0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4EF0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4F30>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4F70>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4FB0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DD4FF0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB050>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB090>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB0D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB110>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB150>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB190>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB1D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB210>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB250>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB290>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB2D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB310>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB350>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB390>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB3D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB410>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB450>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB490>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB4D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB510>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB550>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB590>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB5D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB610>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB650>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB690>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB6D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB710>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB750>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB790>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB7D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB810>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB850>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB890>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB8D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB910>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB950>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB990>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCB9D0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBA10>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBA50>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBA90>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBAD0>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBB10>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBB50>, <twitter.Status object at 0x01DCBB90>]
```

I am new to Python and also new to Twitter Api .

Comment: Looks like a correct result to me, check your docs what's a `Status` object

Comment: I said I am new to Twitter Api so can you please tell me how I check Status Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the twitter module. Your query returns a List of instances of the twitter.Status class. A short documentation of twitter.Status can be found here: http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html#Status

You could do:

```
tweets=api.GetSearch("Ghaza",per_page=100,page=1)
for t in tweets:
  print t.text
```

According to http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/, you can find more documentation with these three commands run from shell:

```
$ pydoc twitter.Status
$ pydoc twitter.User
$ pydoc twitter.DirectMessage
```

Comment: thanks , this is what I want. If I want to get result from specific dates than I have to do the same task ?

Comment: @munieb Sorry, I don't know the python-twitter API that well. You'll have to read the API documentation, or ask that as another question. I recommend posting such questions with the `python-twitter`-tag